# Header when creating report from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I Have some code which creates a header in Word from Excel:

```
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport").Range("I4").Text
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
```

But an error occurs on the last row.
What I want to create with that row is that I want the header to be nice centerd.

This is how it is using the code. ( not what I want )

[image]

and this is how I want it to look

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Try to change order of your instructions and, which is important, you need to add a special line break character at the and to get 'justification result'. Here is an example:

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
Selection.TypeText "here is text from Excel" + Chr(11)
```

**Option 2:**
However, justification will not give you the result you presented as aligning words add extra spaced between each word. To get result which you have you need to add table which could go like this:

```
Dim tmpTBL As Table
Set tmpTBL = Selection.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, 2)

With tmpTBL.Cell(1, 1).Range
    .Text = "Date: " & Now
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
End With
With tmpTBL.Cell(1, 2).Range
    .Text = "here is text from Excel"
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
End With
```

The following screen shot presents both options.
[image]